# Linking against a dylib which is not safe for use in application extensions

Tags: xcode, ios-app-extension

I have a share extension in my app and when I'm building I'm getting the following error:

> linking against a dylib which is not safe for use in application extensions: PATH_TO_MY_NON_EXTENSION_SAFE_FRAMEWORK_TARGET`

The reported framework (which is another target in the same project) is really not an extension-safe framework.

The problem is that I've never linked my share extension against that framework. I've only linked it against another extension-safe-API framework, and my pods framework, which are, recursively speaking, explicitly marked as extension-safe. Nothing in the dependency/link tree ever touches my `NON_EXTENSION_SAFE_FRAMEWORK_TARGET`, though I'm getting a warning.

What might be causing this?

I am on Xcode 9.2.

Comment: Did you ever fix this issue? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: An old question but does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52995169/372347) help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [warning message linking against a dylib which is not safe for use in application extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52885293/warning-message-linking-against-a-dylib-which-is-not-safe-for-use-in-application)

Answer (score 2):

> The problem is that I've never linked my share extension against that framework.

I had the same issue - the framework was NOT included in `Link Binary with Libraries` of my extension Target. So I couldn't figure out why it was giving that error.

I found that I had a file that had the code:

```
import TheFramework
```

And that file's `Target Membership` included the extension target.

Remove any file that imports the framework from the extension's target membership.