# warning message linking against a dylib which is not safe for use in application extensions

Tags: ios, frameworks

I am receiving an error that says

> linking against a dylib which is not safe for use in application extensions

I have looked at the other questions that address this, the only one that had answers did not solve my problem, and the rest had received no answers at all.

I tried just building a framework with nothing in it at all, and adding the framework to Linked Frameworks and Libraries in the General tab of my intents app extension, and I still get this message.

When I add code to the framework, I still get the warning message.

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class Widget: NSObject {

}
```

I am sure to follow instructions at [Some APIs Are Unavailable to App Extensions](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH2-SW6)
 and at [Using an Embedded Framework to Share Code](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html) but I still get the same warning message. I have read that Apple App Store will not pass my app for review if I have this issue.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you are linking against a framework you control, select the framework target in your project. In the **General** tab, look at **Deployment Info** and you will see a line:

```
App Extensions: [ ] Allow app extension API only
```

Select the checkbox, and you should be able to link against this framework.

This checkbox ensures that only calls to APIs that are valid within App Extensions are used.
[image: Framework Target General Tab]

Answer (score 5):

In Xcode 14, I couldn't find the checkbox shown in [@lar3ry's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52995169/809944).

However, the setting can still be found in the "Build Settings" tab under Build Options > Require Only App-Extension-Safe API. Make sure to select "All" setting, not only "Basic":

[image]

The `xcconfig`-style build setting name is `APPLICATION_EXTENSION_API_ONLY`.